# Foreign key constraint failure because of different data between primary key and foreign key - MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert records into a database I have created with MySQL. However, there is one table that I can't seem to get data into. I am getting a `Lock Wait Timeout Exceeded` warning, and when I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` this is the output I get:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2023-02-23 15:55:19 0x491c Transaction:
TRANSACTION 6740, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 57428, OS thread handle 18716, query id 363298 localhost 127.0.0.1 sqluser update
INSERT INTO quiz_submission (quiz_submission_id, submission_time, quiz_submission_attempts, quiz_submission_time_spent, quiz_submission_kept_score, quiz_id, student_id)  VALUES (58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-03T04:24:26Z', 1, 558917, 8.0, 3209045, 17401),(58434099, '2022-05-0
Foreign key constraint fails for table `canvas_student_info`.`quiz_submission`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_quiz_submission_student1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index fk_quiz_submission_student1_idx tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 800043f9; asc   C ;;
 1: len 4; hex 837ba233; asc  { 3;;

But in parent table `canvas_student_info`.`student`, in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80007738; asc   w8;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000001947; asc      G;;
 2: len 7; hex 81000001070137; asc       7;;
 3: len 14; hex 4d696e646920416e646572736f6e; asc Mindi Anderson;;
 4: len 15; hex 416e646572736f6e2c204d696e6469; asc Anderson, Mindi;;
 5: len 4; hex 8002c866; asc    f;;
```

The odd thing is that when I check the data I am trying to insert, it matches the primary key of the other table exactly.

I will include my code as well, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# %%
import json
import mysql.connector
import requests
import config
import pandas as pd

# %%
#login to local instance server
dbUser = config.dbUser
dbPassword = config.dbPassword
dbName = config.dbName # name of the database


#login into Canvas API, current instructor Key
course = config.course #Econ151 S22
token = config.token

# %%
def insertIntoQuizSubmission(rows):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=dbUser, password=dbPassword, database=dbName)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    add_student = ("INSERT INTO quiz_submission (quiz_submission_id, submission_time, quiz_submission_attempts, quiz_submission_time_spent, quiz_submission_kept_score, quiz_id, student_id) " + " VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    # Insert World Population
    cursor.executemany(add_student, rows)

    # Make sure data is committed to the database
    cnx.commit()

    if cnx.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
    print("closed")

# %%
def retrieveTableData(column, table):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=dbUser, password=dbPassword, database=dbName)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT {column} FROM {table}')

    results = cursor.fetchall()

    return results

# %%
quiz_ids = []
quiz_id_tuple = retrieveTableData('quiz_id','quiz')
for i in quiz_id_tuple:
    quiz_ids.append(i[0])

# %%
student_ids = []
student_id_tuple = retrieveTableData('student_id','student')
for i in student_id_tuple:
    student_ids.append(i[0])

# %%
pageNum = 1
isNextPage = True
responses = []
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
for student_id in student_ids:
    for quiz_id in quiz_ids:
        endpoint = "https://byui.instructure.com:443/api/v1/courses/" + str(course) + "/quizzes/" + str(quiz_id) + "/submissions?page=" + str(pageNum)
        response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
        responseJson = response.json()
        responses.append(responseJson)

# %%
print(responses[0]["quiz_submissions"][0]["id"])

# %%
quiz_submissions = []

for response in responses:
    submission = response["quiz_submissions"]
    for quiz_submission in submission:
            for student_id in student_ids:
                currSubmission = (
                    quiz_submission["id"],
                    quiz_submission["finished_at"],
                    quiz_submission["attempt"],
                    quiz_submission["time_spent"],
                    quiz_submission["kept_score"],
                    quiz_submission["quiz_id"],
                    quiz_submission["user_id"]
                )

                quiz_submissions.append(currSubmission)

# %%
insertIntoQuizSubmission(quiz_submissions)
```

I have tried multiple steps to check the data I am entering to ensure it is the same data and it does not match.

I have also seen similar questions but they do not provide an effective answer for my particular problem.

Comment: Can you cross-check `student` table; 
Whether the `student_id` you are trying to insert in `quiz_submission` already exists in `student` table.

Comment: @tushar I checked and the Id does already exist in the student table

Comment: OK,
There can be other reasons. Such as syntax error.
I am not sure who marked this questions as duplicate and closed it; But I can try to find answer from your error log

Comment: @Tushar Thank you! I appreciate your assistance!